# How to hide a menu list item

Tags: html, hide, menuitem

I have a web page and in that few menu item using
`<ul> <li>`. I want one menu item to be invisible from the public. Can anybody tell me how to achieve this one?

Comment: Add style="display:none;" to the li element?

Comment: ya @RichAndrews, i did as you told. it worked fine. thank you dude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<ul>    
  <li></li>
  <li class="invisible"><li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a class or id to the specific menu item and in css:

```
li.class {
display: none;
}
```

or with an ID

```
#id {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set css propery of any li tag to display:none and to hide whole menu you can set ul tag css property to `display:none`

```
<ul style="display:none"> for whole menu

<li style="display:none"> for menu item one or more
```